# accdb and .net; open database error

Tags: .net, ms-access

I'm trying to open access database from my .net application, C#, but I'm still getting this error:
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException(0x80040E4D): Cannot start your application.
... the file is missing or corrupt.

When I open database and run application at the same time. I get error:
the file is opened by another user.

here's my connection string, in general form:

```
OleDbConnection con;
con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=path_to_database\database.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database;Password=admin;");
con.open();      // error(exception) here
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a spurious semicolon in your connection string:

```
;Jet OLEDB:Database;Password=admin;
```

should be

```
;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=admin;
```

Comment: Thanks but that's not it.